# wxWidgets - Alpha blending

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, alpha, alphablending

Is there a way in wxWidget to do alpha blending operations such as multiplying the alpha of a bitmap versus the RGB of other bitmap to generate new images (such as rendering a photo as an anti-aliased circular shape).

Comment: I will love to know how to do this as well. Atm i use region to get solid alpha working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I haven't done alpha blending myself, I believe the wxGraphicContext is what you are after.
http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxgraphicscontext.html
I've got flicker free drawing into the graphics context (on Win32) using the following in my paint event handler:

```
void OnPaint( wxPaintEvent& e )
{
    wxBufferedPaintDC dc( this );        
    wxGraphicsContext* gdc = wxGraphicsContext::Create( dc );
    // you drawing code here
}
```

EDIT: this email trail might offer some more insight:
[http://www.nabble.com/Is-alpha-blending-implemented-when-using-DC's--td17183159.html](http://www.nabble.com/Is-alpha-blending-implemented-when-using-DC%27s--td17183159.html)

Comment: Hum, it's not exactly that. Let's say I have a square image. The blit method in the DC or the equivalent in the wxGraphicsContext only allows you to render the whole bitmap or rectangular portions. How would I be able to render just a circular area of my original image.

Usually I would render a circle to the destination buffer making sure it was cleared out to 255 alpha beforehand. Then I would just alpha blend the image against the buffer multiplying alpha values against the individual RGB components. 
I guess I'll do this manually... I'll post the implementation.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the DrawBitmap method of the wxGraphicsContext does not pay attention to the Alpha channel when drawing?  As a complete aside, you could also use OpenGL to draw your images as wxWidgets has an OpenGL canvas.

Comment: This is the code I'd like to work:

wxBitmap my_image = LoadSomePngWithNoAlpha();
wxBitmap buffer;
wxMemoryDc dc = new wxMemoryDc(buffer);
dc.SetBrush(wxCoulor(0, 0, 0, 0));
dc.Clear();
dc.BlitBitmapAsCircle(bitmap, wxPoint(5,5), 42.0);

In order to do this final step you would usually draw a normal circle with alpha set to 255 and then if I blend in the wxBitmap which is rectangular to the buffer, only the alpha == 255 bit will be copied so I would end up with a circular cropped section of the Png image.

Comment: The link I posted shows you how to use a wxMemoryDc with the wxGraphicsContext.  When using OpenGL (for example) you would draw the transparent circle into the alpha channel of the image before drawing the image.  I expect this is what you need to do here - though there may not be good API support to do this sort of stuff.

Comment: Hum, I'll try that approach later on. I'll get back to this thread with results. Thanks!

Comment: I will probably be playing with the wxGraphicsContext next week, so I'll have a look at alpha blending too if I get a chance.